# How to output "EVEN" for even numbers between 1 and 100?

Tags: c#, .net

How to write C# code that lists out object array value int 1-100 and output string text "EVEN" when it detect that object converted to int is divisible by 2?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       object[] numbers = new object[100];

        numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Cast<object>().ToArray();


        foreach (object number in numbers)
        {
            if(Convert.ToInt32(number) % 2 == 0)
            {
                number.ToString().Equals("Even");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
        Console.Read();
     }
}
```

Comment: Why not use an int[] ? Would simplify the code a lot already. And you have to output "EVEN", not compare the value of e.g 10 to "EVEN"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is here:

```
number.ToString().Equals("Even");
```

This is getting the string representation of `number` and then comparing it for equality against the string `Even`, and doing nothing with the result.  If you take a step back and think about this, it doesn't make any sense, because you want to print `Even` if `number` is even.

With your current program, you can do that like this:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(number) % 2 == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is even", number);
}
```

That said, there are a few things with your program that could be improved, as it doesn't seem as though you've got the hang of C#'s type system just yet.

Firstly, you are declaring an array of 100 objects like so:

```
object[] numbers = new object[100];
```

You already know you want to work with integers, so, instead of using `object`, you should use `int`:

```
int[] numbers = new int[100];
```

Next, you're generating a sequence of integers from `1`-`100`:

```
numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

`Enumerable.Range()` returns a collection of integers, and `.ToArray()` converts that to an array of integers.  As we're now using an array of integers, there is no need to cast them to `object`, so this can be simplified to:

```
numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();
```

There is one further simplification that can be made to this.  `Enumerable.Range()` returns an `IEnumerable<int>`, which represents a collection of integers.  This means that instead of declaring an array of 100 integers, generating a collection of integers, converting those to an array, and assigning them to `numbers`, we can do this instead:

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
```

There is another change that can be made here, but I'll describe at the end of this answer so let's look at the loop:

```
foreach (object number in numbers)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(number) % 2 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```

As we've changed the code to use `IEnumerable<int>` instead of `object[]`, we can now change the declaration of the loop to:

```
foreach (int number in numbers)
```

This is possible because a type that implements `IEnumerable` allows you to use `foreach`.  As another example, if we had a collection of students:

```
IEnumerable<Student> students = GetStudents();
```

We could loop over those like this:

```
foreach (Student student in students)
```

Going back to your loop, now that `number` is an `int`, we don't have to convert it from an `object` to an `int` before we can check if it's even or not.  So the loop's code can be simplified to:

```
foreach (int number in numbers)
{
    if (number % 2 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is even", number);
    }
}
```

The main thing to understand is that when you already know what type you'd like to use, you should always use it whenever you can, as it will always simplify the code you write.  The complete program would now look like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);

        foreach (int number in numbers)
        {
            if (number % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is even", number);
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

As for the other change I mentioned, your integer generation code could be simplified to:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
```

The `var` keyword is making use of [implicit type inference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb384061.aspx) to determine `numbers` type.  Similarly, the loop could also be changed to:

```
foreach (var number in numbers)
```

I wouldn't worry about implicit type inference for the moment.  I'm mentioning more for the sake of completeness, but you should learn to use the type system properly first.

Comment: OVER All Fix was this if-else statement. Thank a lot for your help sorry for late reply. 

if (Convert.ToInt32(number) % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("is even");
                }
                else if(!(Convert.ToInt32(number) % 2 == 0))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(number);
                }

Answer (score 2):

Your code is *almost* correct (except for the `.Equals("Even")` part).  Your code inside the `foreach`can be simplified to:

```
       Console.WriteLine(number.ToString() + ((Convert.ToInt32(number) % 2) == 0 ? " is even" : ""));
```

}

Comment: Hey ffa I'm getting syntax error on: Console.WriteLine(number.ToString() + Convert.ToInt32(number) % 2 == 0 ? " is even" : "" );

Comment: Edited user3151548. Note that if you see a compile error and can correct it, feel free to edit the post. Otherwise, including the error(s) in the comments may help with getting it resolved quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code snippets.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        var numbers = new List<object>();
        numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Cast<object>      ().ToList();            
        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(number) % 2 == 0)               
                stringBuilder.Append("EVEN");                
            else
                stringBuilder.Append(number);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this snippets could solve your problems

Comment: Instead of just posting some code, you could improve your answer by explaining what you changed and why.